# "How to simulate a set of raw data based on a known median (quartile)"

Tags: r, excel, python-3.x

How to simulate a set of raw data based on a known median (quartile),such as 10.9 (9.2-13.3)?In addition, Number of cases (n) is 100.

I have tried rand function with excel and python,while don't get the results I want.

import numpy as np

I want to simulate a set of raw data based on 10.9 (9.2-13.3) with 100 cases.

Comment: Here's one way in R: `c(rep(9.2, 49), rep(10.9, 2), rep(13.3, 49))`. You need to assume more than quartiles in order to build any meaningful simulation.

Comment: In R just by specifying the `median`, you cannot generate meaningfully, either specify the type of distribution, or some other parameter to generate data. Though below I have mentioned a method to get data by specifying `mean` and also compared the deviance with `median`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to generate random numbers between specific range and with specific mean

Used `mean` in place of `median`:

```
require("Runuran")
d1 <- urnorm(n = 100, mean = 10.9, lb = 9.2, ub = 13.3)

summary(d1)
sd(d1)
hist(d1)
```

To check the results you can use this (check the difference between `mean` and `median`):

```
round(c(n=length(d1), median=median(d1)), 2)
```

Comment: I want a non-normally distributed data type.

Comment: Non-normally type is a very vast term, specify the exact type of distribution of the data.

Answer (score 0):

The original question is meaningful if the max and min are specified also.  The following function will do the trick. It works for any of the 9 quantile types in the quantile function, and for the quantile definition in the boxplot function.  The size must be > 6, because some quartile specs are not possible for N = 6.  (My original interest was in simulating data to match given boxplots; it is easy to modify the function to take whiskers and outliers as part of the input.)

```
qsim <- function(N, quantsin, type = 7, tiebreaking = TRUE){
  # Simulate data so that the R quantile function will give the input quartiles
  # Parameter quantsin is a 5 component vector of input quartiles
  
  # input error checking
  if (N <= 6){stop("Set size must be greater than 6")}
  if (!(type %in% c(1:9) | (type == "boxplot")) ) {stop("Invalid type")}
  if (!identical(quantsin, sort(quantsin))){stop("Invalid quartiles")}
  if (length(quantsin) != 5){stop("Invalid quartiles")}
  
  # determine how the quartiles are defined for this N
  # the information will be contained in the matrix indices
  if (type == "boxplot"){
    res <- boxplot(1:N, plot = FALSE) # no plot, we just need the output
    quants = c(min(res$stats[1, 1], res$out), res$stats[2:4, 1], 
               max(res$stats[5, 1], res$out))
  } else {quants <- quantile(1:N, type = type)}
  
  indices <- matrix(rep(NA_real_, 10), nrow = 5, 
              dimnames = list(quartiles = 0:4, position = c("low", "high")))
  indices[1, "high"] <- quants[1] # will always be 1
  for(q in 2:4){indices[q, ] <- c(floor(quants[q]), ceiling(quants[q]))}
  indices[5, "low"] <- quants[5] # will always be N
  
  # begin to build the output. 
  # ties may be created for quantiles 1:3
  outvec <- rep(NA_real_, N)
  outvec[indices[1, "high"]] <- quantsin[1]
  for(q in 2:4){
    outvec[indices[q, "low"]] <- outvec[indices[q, "high"]] <- quantsin[q]
    }
  outvec[indices[5, "low"]] <- quantsin[5]
  
  # assign intermediate entries, if there is any room
  assignintermediates <- function(lowerindex, higherindex){
    if(higherindex - lowerindex > 1) {
      outvec[(lowerindex + 1): (higherindex - 1) ] <<- 
        # sorting makes the tie breaking easier
        sort(runif(higherindex - lowerindex - 1, min = outvec[lowerindex], 
                   max = outvec[higherindex]))
    }
  }
  for(q in 1:4){
    assignintermediates(indices[q, "high"], indices[q + 1, "low"])
    }
  
  # optionally break any ties we forced above
  # ties will remain if two input quartiles are equal, which is allowed
  # the overall function would also work without this tie breaking
  if(tiebreaking){
    breakties <- function(q){
      if(indices[q, "low"] == indices[q, "high"]) {return(NULL)} 
      # take advantage of the fact that outvec is sorted
      epsilon <- min(outvec[indices[q, "low"]] - outvec[indices[q, "low"] - 1],
                  outvec[indices[q, "high"] + 1] - outvec[indices[q, "high"]])
      if(epsilon == 0){return(NULL)} # can't break the tie
      # use the proper interpolation formula 
      outvec[indices[q, "low"]] <<- outvec[indices[q, "low"]] - 
        (quants[q] - floor(quants[q]))*epsilon
      outvec[indices[q, "high"]] <<- outvec[indices[q, "high"]] + 
        (ceiling(quants[q]) - quants[q])*epsilon
    }
    for(q in 2:4){breakties(q)}
  } # end of optional tiebreaking
  outvec
}
```

And a bit of checking

```
checkafew <- function(){
  N <- 14; 
  type <- 7
  quantile(1:N) # note the interpolation at Q1, Q2, and Q3
  (qin <- c(0, 1, 5, 6, 7))
  outset <- qsim(N, qin, type = type) 
  quantile(outset, type = type) # agrees
  length(outset); length(unique(outset)) # no ties
  
  outset <- qsim(N, qin, type = type, tiebreaking = FALSE) 
  quantile(outset, type = type) # agrees
  length(outset); length(unique(outset)) # three ties, as expected
  
  N <- 15; 
  type <- 8
  quantile(1:N, type = type) # note the interpolation at Q1, and Q3
  (qin <- c(0, 1, 5, 5, 7))
  outset <- qsim(N, qin, type = type) 
  quantile(outset, type = type) # agrees
  length(outset); length(unique(outset)) # some ties couldn't be broken
}
```